# How do I crop an image with just one or a few layers with Pixelmator?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, pixelmator

The task I'm trying to achieve with Pixelmator is opening up a PSD and quickly (because I generally have to do it a lot) crop a piece of the image but also removing layers that I don't want in the finished picture.

This is for making little pictures out of PSD created by graphic designers to be later used in  web application (for example, if there's a round button, I want the button, the icon inside but not the background, it has to be transparent, so I want to remove or hide those layers).

[I'm evaluating Pixelmator as an alternative to Photoshop to process PSDs into HTML and CSS.](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5894/software-to-replace-photoshop-for-a-programmer)

Comment: This might be useful info, or not. http://abduzeedo.com/basics-slicing-pixelmator ( I didn't read it. )

Comment: So is the question really "how do I turn layers on and off in Pixelmator"?

Comment: @e100: How to figure out which layers to turn on and off is also part of the question. Or maybe there's a way to just copy the contents of one layer without having to turn them on and off at all.