# Free editor to render a custom logotype on different goods?

Tags: print-design, software-recommendation

I need a free editor (online or offline) to apply a logo on different goods, like pens, t-shirts, cards and so on.

**UPDATED**
I don't need to draw a logotype, I have it already. Just I need a some tools to see quickly print it on many things (card, cups, T-shirts,...). To see how it looks printed on different things.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lower-cost alternative to Photoshop](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5894/lower-cost-alternative-to-photoshop)

Comment: GIMP is a free raster image editor - if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: @usr2564301, nope, software, of course. Just to make a preview of the logotype on some object (i.e. office things: cups, visit cards, pens and so on).

Comment: @Lucian While I feel like that question is one possible answer to this question, I think this question is distinct from it because there can be (and likely is) tools specifically created for previewing logos on different mediums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To preview your logo and text printed on various promotional products you can take advantage of the free preview feature available from some promotional product manufacturer sites like [VistaPrint:](https://www.vistaprint.com/?no_redirect=1&xnav=logo)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### I. Mockup

If you can find a free (or paid if you choose) mockup of the good you want, just use **any raster editor** with a transparent png of your logo and adapt the perspective.

**Gimp, Paint.net**, etc.

Check the licensing of the mockup files.

### II. 3D Render

Personally, I prefer making a new 3D render. If you want to model the goods, a can, a bottle use **Blender**. You can probably find some 3D models that can be imported into Blender.

Another option is to use **Sketchup**, where you could find some free 3D models, and make a photorealistic render using a free renderer like **Kerkythea or Yafray**.

### III. Conceptual art

But you could try your own style. Using the logo on a silhouette, a watercolor paint, a surrealist Tshirt... That could be an interesting option.

In that case, you could use, either Gimp again or a vector based program like **Inkscape** or **Gravity design**.

Comment: Blender with free models and Inkscape are good for my targets

Answer (score 1):

***If*** you already have Adobe CS full suite subscription... you can add C4D Lite (comes with After Effects) plugin for Illustrator to create render onto objects previews live in Illustrator with your art.

[image]

And if not, for quick 3D renders mapped onto cups, T-shirts, bags etc, [***Blender***](https://www.blender.org/) may be your best bet.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately, I haven't Adobe subscription but Blender is really very convenient.

Answer (score -2):

You simply can try logomaker https://www.logaster.com/ or you just get good inspiration from galleries.

Comment: We are looking for long detailed answers here on GDSE, not just a single sentence with a link. Also, answers that look like yours are suspiciously similar to SPAM, and are often deleted by the admins here.  If you can expand on what this "logomaker" service can do, with some examples perhaps you can save your answer.

Comment: It's almost that I need but I don't need to generate my logotype, just to I uploaded it on the site and it was printed on these things.

Comment: Billy already said GIMP is what you need.

Comment: @Lucian, yap, I can make it by GIMP, even in the Paint... but it isn't special app for these targets, it's an image editor... cool editor.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to make it looks like a spam and I didn't understand a question for first. Шах, I prefer Affinity photo and Pixlr. They have all basic functions.